# Javascript - innerHTML function in IE

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have a html file with  content

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
    function fun1()
    {
        alert(document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML);
    }
</script>
<div id="id1">
    <ul>
        <li>Here111</li>
        <li>Here222</li>
        <li>Here333</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="fun1()">Click</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In innerHTML function iam getting only

```
<ul>
    <li>Here111
    <li>Here222
    <li>Here333</li>
</ul>
```

The `</li>` tag is missing how can I get entire content?

Comment: As you claim it does not work for you - post your entire page, there must be some other thing that does not work. @Bitsplitter wrote a page that works fine for IE 6-8.

Comment: I see that I did not evaluate my own solution properly. I was concentrating on seeing the </ul> that is missing in your original question. That appears in IE just fine but you are right, the first </li> is missing in my sample too in both IE7 and 8.

Comment: Is their any solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` in the beginning of html

Comment: If switching to standards mode fixed this, then you should run your HTML through an HTML validator because it probably means you have some semi-serious errors somewhere in it.

Answer (score 1):

Your script refers to an id called **test1** but your html hasn't got any.

If you do it like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function test(){
                alert(document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test1">
            <ul>
                <li>This is first</li>
                <li>This is Second</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="#" onclick="test();">hhhhhh</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

it works fine even in IE 7/8.

Answer (score 1):

You have set id of div as a "test"
but you are getting it by "test1"

```
alert(document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML);
```

it should be

```
alert(document.getElementById("test").innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

There also is outerHTML property (unfortunately, unsupported in some browsers). It returns the whole of element.

Answer (score 0):

This is not incorrect. For `<li>` elements, the closing tag is optional in HTML so IE is returning a valid fragment of HTML here (not that it always does).

If you need closing tags, you'll need to do create your own HTML string by traversing the DOM.

Comment: Given the above HTML doc, you might argue that it is not incorrect (albeit horribly inconsistent on IE's part since it does close the last `li` explicitly...). However, IE will give the same `innerHTML` when using any XHTML doctype as well, in which case I'd like to argue that it IS wrong.

Comment: @Gustav: I disagree: IE doesn't support XHTML. It parses XHTML exactly the same as it parses HTML.